# Can non-color-neutral nucleons exist?

Tags: standard-model, strong-force, confinement, color-charge

In a proton or neutron, one quark is red, another blue, and the last green, making it color neutral. Is it possible for a nucleon to consist of colors rgg, rbb, rrb, etc? If three quarks of such color collided with each other, would they form a non-color-neutral nucleon?

Comment: Do you know that color-charged objects are [confined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement)?

Comment: yes, if they separate far enough, a new quark will be created from the energy expended to separate them and it will make a new quark pair. Are you saying that its not possible for such a situation to occur?